# How do I distribute JMS Listener Connections to ActiveMQ Network of Brokers using Spring Boot JMS?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms

Our JMS Listener application connects to an ActiveMQ network of brokers through a load balancer, which we are told distributes connections amongst brokers in a round-robin fashion. Our spring boot application is creating a connection via the load balancer, which in turn feeds the connection to one of the brokers amongst the network of brokers. If a message is published to the brokers then it would be a lot quicker if the message was on the broker that the JMS listener connection lived on. However, the likelihood of that occurring is slim unless we can distribute the connections across the brokers.

I've tried increasing the `concurrency` in the `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory`, but that didn't do the trick. I was thinking about somehow extending the `AbstractJmsListenerContainerFactory`, and somehow create a `Map` of `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` instances but it looks like the `createListenerContainer` will only return an instance of whatever is parameterized in the `AbstractJmsListenerContainerFactory` and we cannot parameterize it with an instance of `Map`.

We are using Spring Boot 1.5.14.RELEASE.

== UPDATE ==

I've been playing around with the classes above, and it seems like it is inherent in Spring JMS that a Jms Listener be associated with a Single Message Listener Container, which in turn is associated with a single (potentially shared) connection.

For any folks that have JMS Application Listeners that are connecting to a load balanced network of brokers, are you creating a single connection that is connecting to a single broker, and if so, do you experience significant performance degradation as a result of the network of brokers having to move any inbound messages to a broker with consumers?

Comment: My first thought here is that if the volume of consumers and/or message is so low that you're concerned with extra hops like this then you may not need a network of brokers in the first place. Typically a network of brokers is deployed when the number of clients and messages is too great for a single broker to handle in which case there should be sufficient consumers on every broker in the network to deal with incoming messages so that message hops between the nodes are relatively rare and statistically insignificant.

Comment: @JustinBertram - We are expecting that the volume of our consumers and messages for these APIs to be really high which is why we don't want the extra overhead of messages being transferred between brokers to the one that has the consumer connection within it.

Comment: If you expect a high number of consumers won't the load-balancer ensure that the consumers are fairly evenly distributed among the brokers in the network which will essentially eliminate the possibility that messages will need to be transferred to other brokers?

Comment: BTW, `concurrency` just applies to the number of *consumers* on the connection and not the number of connections itself.

Comment: There are more brokers than there are listeners because the brokers service more than just our application. In order to work around the problem, we've increased the number listener application instances to match the number of brokers in the environment. However, we were hoping to programatically solve that issue through Spring JMS by increasing the number of JMS connections to the broker for a single JMS listener application.